# C#: How to check whether a instance is serializable

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can check whether a instance is marked as serializable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Type t = typeof(x) 
        for fields:
        t.GetFields().Where(p=> !p.Attributes.HasFlag(FieldAttributes.NotSerialized));
        for type
        t.Attributes.HasFlag(TypeAttributes.Serializable);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
typeof(MyClass).IsSerializable;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are asking for instance, and not class, the correct answer is actually:

```
o.GetType().IsSerializable;
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried?

```
o.GetType().FindInterfaces().Any(x => x == typeof(ISerializable));
```

Comment: If you are checking for implementation of an interface, wouldn't it be better to just use (o is ISerializable) instead of dragging Reflection into this?