# How to check whether an instance is fully serializable?

Tags: c#, serialization

Is there a way of checking whether an instance is fully serializable in C#? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163266/c-how-to-check-whether-a-instance-is-serializable) does not give the full answer for a nested type. Consider this example:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class MyContainer
{
    private int m_foo;
    private MyReference m_reference;
    public MyContainer(int foo, MyReference reference)
    {
         m_foo = foo;
         m_reference = reference;
    }
    // ... other stuff
}

// This is not serializable
public class MyReference : MarshalByRefObject
{
   // ... Some methods and some data
}

public void Test()
{
    var m = new MyContainer(1, new MyReference());
    Assert.That(m.GetType().IsSerializable); // fine. This is true.
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(new MemoryStream(), m); // This gets the ZONK.
}
```

Is there a simple way of telling whether an instance is recursively serializable without trying (which, for my use case, would be to expensive)?

Comment: Blunt `try { ... serialize ... } catch` would do. I wonder why `MyContainer` is defined as serializable though. It's not.

Comment: I would recommend avoiding BinaryFormatter, it is slow, produces large files, and is fragile. I would recommend just about anything else. Json or Protobuf are good alternatives for text/binary. However, most serialization libraries have different rules and attributes for serialization, so there is difficult to suggest anything general. Writing unit-tests is probably the best approach to ensure types are serializable.

Comment: I know that `BinaryFormatter` has it's issues, but for my use case there's likely no feasible alternative for now (or at least, that's up for later). In .NET Framework, the above class can be marshalled, but in .NET Core this no longer works, because the Remoting infrastructure is gone. I'm trying to work around this.

Comment: @Sinatr Yea, but exceptions are expensive. And it doesn't really help, because if it fails, I would still need to somehow decipher why and split up the members. But maybe I start out with that first.

Comment: Can you just mark that known problem child as [non-serializable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nonserializedattribute?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: @Nikki9696: Not for my actual use case, because at the spot where the serialization happens doesn't know anything about what it's going to get. There's an `if (t.IsSerializable) { ... serialize ... } else if (t is MarshalByRef) { write reference } else { throw ... }` around everything. And the problem now happens when the type _is_ serializable, but it's contents are not.